# Google places API key error

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I am developing a project and I have to use google places api for web. I am using google api for location name drop down menu. When I fill out location name, I am getting back this response. I have generated api key and embedded it my code but this doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestion?

> /**/*xdc*._62n6tn && *xdc*._62n6tn( [3,null,null,"This service requires an >API key.  For more information
>   on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: >https://developers.google.com
>   /maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key"] )

edit:
Ok here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Retrieving Autocomplete Predictions</title>
 <style>
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  #right-panel {
    font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

  #right-panel select, #right-panel input {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  #right-panel select {
    width: 100%;
  }

  #right-panel i {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="right-panel">
    <p>Query suggestions for 'Taxi Services near NewY':</p>
    <ul id="results"></ul>
  </div>
  <script>

  function initService() {
    var displaySuggestions = function(predictions, status) {
      if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        return;
      }

      predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prediction.description));
        document.getElementById('results').appendChild(li);
      });
    };

    var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    service.getQueryPredictions({ input: 'Taxi Services near NewY' }, displaySuggestions);
  }
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIza---------------------&</script>
```

and here's the 
[google api settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh2AP.png)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  Sounds like you aren't including the key correctly or haven't activated the key.

Comment: Are you sure "abcd" is your key ? As i see at the bottom of your code .Put correct key there.

Comment: I have added all details. Please have a look.

Comment: Have you enabled Google Maps Javascript API in your Console . Check if you correctly enabled API key for this API .It will definitely work .

Comment: I tried my API key with your code and it worked !! Tell me one thing what kind of API key are you creating server or browser ? Or just disable the Google Maps Javascript API and enable again and then generate a new key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing steps .
1. Go to Google Developers Console.
2. Enable Google Maps Javascript API.
3. Then Generate API key .
4. Then put that API key in the bottom of your code in this section.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_JAVASCRIPT_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initService"
    async defer></script>
```

This will 100% work, if follow the steps carefully.

Comment: How foolish of me. Thank you for saving my life :)